# Blender File Lags with Grease Pencil Tool

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I have a specific Blender file that lags really badly every time I draw a new grease pencil stroke. I've tried drawing in a fresh Blender file, and it works fine. So I'm thinking this file has some weird settings or something to cause this delay. Once I draw a stroke it becomes completely unresponsive for a few seconds before I can draw another one, or even do anything else. The file size isn't that big either so I'm a bit stumped. Here's [the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rinP3XkNCF-Jiu7l95VmEtt9sOzws_De/view?usp=sharing) for reference. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's a screen recording as well showing two Blender projects side by side. The project on the left has no issues with drawing new strokes. The one on the right doesn't record all the strokes. After one stroke is made, the program freezes for a few seconds before I can draw again. Sometimes this lasts a long time too.

Left side - project without lag ................................ Right side - project with lag

[image]

Computer stats:
[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing any lag from your file (probably not what you wanted to hear, sorry!).  What's your input device?

Comment: really strange. maybe it's my computer or something. Is that what you mean by input device? I'm drawing on a Surface Pro 6. I'll add a snapshot of my stats in the main question

Comment: It's definitely settings in the file. I tried opening a new project with the same file settings and that file also lags when I use grease pencil. The problem goes away when I use Blender's 2D Animation workspace, but my custom workspace looks to be the common denominator. That said, I wonder which settings caused this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm chalking this up to my computer being too slow, and Blender taking a lot of CPU. I reverted to an earlier version of the file and appended all my progress and it solved the issue.